# Javax mime message part.getFileName is returning truncated attachment file name

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, imap, email-attachments

We are using javax.mail(1.5.5) API to retrieve the emails from the inbox. When trying to get the attachment file name by calling `mimePart.getFileName()`, the attachment file name got truncated.

**Case 1:**
Got truncated file name, When mimePart.getFileName() is called it returned **supplementary_skip_trace_-*ctc1ao5968xxx*-_xxxxxxxx_xxxxxxxx** with below email source.

```
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; 
    name*0=supplementary_skip_trace_-_ctc1ao5968xxx_-_xxxxxxxx_xxxxxxxx; 
    name*1=x_2207168.pdf
Content-Disposition: attachment; 
    filename*0=supplementary_skip_trace_-_ctc1ao5968xxx_-_xxxxxxxx_xxxxxxxx; 
    filename*1=x_2207168.pdf
```

**Case 2:**
Got complete file name, When mimePart.getFileName() is called it returned, it returned complete file name **supplementary_skip_trace_-*ctc1ao5968xxx*-_xxxxxxxx_xxxxxxxxx_2207168.pdf**

```
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; 
    name=supplementary_skip_trace_-_ctc1ao5968xxx_-_xxxxxxxx_xxxxxxxxx_2207168.pdf
Content-Disposition: attachment; 
    filename=supplementary_skip_trace_-_ctc1ao5968xxx_-_xxxxxxxx_xxxxxxxxx_2207168.pdf
```

How can we get the full file name with the Case 1?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.